# Ubuntu 18.04 grub menu does not appear

Tags: grub2

Installed ubuntu 18.04 along side with windows 10.
Ubuntu 18.04 grub menu does not appear, and always boots to windows 10.

How can cause the grub menu to appear to select my OS of choice?

Answer (score 0):

You should press <kbd>Shift</kbd> at early boot.